# Caching a processed message for the lifetime of a stream

Tags: akka, akka-stream, akka-http

I am redoing a previous question to make it more focused and clear. 
I have the following situation:

```
case class Hello(u:String) extends A
case class Goodbye extends A
case class GoodbyeAck(u:String) extends B

 val myProcessor: Flow[A, B, Unit] =  Flow[A]
    .map {
      case Hello(u:String) => // I want to cache u (the username)
      case Goodbye => GoodbyeAck(u)
    }
```

So, at the beginning of the stream I get a Hello(username) and at the end of the stream, I receive a Goodbye. I want to reply with Goodbye(username).

How should I cache the username (u) so it will be available for the lifetime of the stream, so I can have it when it's time to say good bye? Is there some context I can leverage? Or do I need to do it outside the framework?

Comment: Since this is append-only data, couldn't just you have a List of usernames you've encountered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like one of the few examples where mutable state is necessary.  Though not "purely functional", the state can be isolated in such a way as to not allow outside influence but still provide the functionality you are looking for.

Note: your question does not specify what B value should be returned by the map in the case of receiving a Hello.  A value of type B is necessary since simply caching is of type Unit.  Therefore a flatMapConcat is used to conform to the requirements of the Flow in the question, which is to return nothing when a Hello is received:

```
def cacheProcessor(defaultString : String = "") : Flow[A, B, Unit] = {

  var userCache : String = defaultString

  Flow[A] flatMapConcat {
    case Hello(u : String) => {
      userCache = u
      Source.empty[B]
    }
    case Goodbye => Source.single[B](GoodbyeAck(userCache))
  }
}//end def cacheProcessor
```

Although userCache is mutable state it cannot be accessed outside of the returned Flow.flatMapConcat.  One important point is that cacheProcessor has to be a `def` so that there is a unique `userCache` for each Flow.

Comment: Thank you. I guess the fix was easier than expected (I had my flow already as a def, but the previous flow was not for some reason, so it was throwing off my results. Your answer gave me confidence that I was on the right path so I worked back through my code.). Still, I think this is a bit inelegant for akka-http users, hopefully there will be some provisions for more elegant server-side session state.

Comment: @WillIAm You are welcome.  I agree it is "a bit inelegant".  I have often contemplated a Flow.map that changes the function being mapped based on a criteria, similar to Actor's become/unbecome functionality.  However, sometimes a simple side-effecting function is better than a convoluted no side effect function.  I think the beauty of scala is that the best of both worlds are always available, even if one is usually preferred..

Comment: Well, the problem with the solution above is that it doesn't scale across multiple flows and multiple stages. As far as I can tell, the "cache" is local to that particular flow. So if I had more complex caching needs, I may have to avoid akka-* for now, just too much headache. But it works for my current needs!

Comment: @WillIAm If you want a cache available across streams then I think the Agent answer I gave to your other question is your best bet...